# Error al insertar a mi base de datos dentro de foreach c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, transacciones

Este es el error que me sale:
El nombre de la variable '@folio' ya ha sido declarado. Los nombres de variables deben ser únicos dentro de un proceso almacenado o lote de consultas.

The variable name '@folio' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Mi variables solo esta declarada una vez.

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadenacc);
        SqlDataAdapter adaptran = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();
        conn.Open();
        SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
        comand.Transaction = tran;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grid.Rows)
            {
 string query = "INSERT INTO ... (FOLIO...) VALUES (@folio,...)";
                comand.CommandText = query;
                comand.Connection = conn;
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", folionew);
                comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 tran.Commit();
```

En el primer recorrido hace el insert correcto pero en el segundo recorrido en donde sale el error y no acabo de entender porque.

Answer (score 5):

El error lo marca porque esta línea

```
comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", folionew);
```

declara, en cada iteración, el parámetro `@folio`.

5 meses después vuelvo con una respuesta a la duda:
En primer lugar, podrías cambiar `comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", folionew);` por `comand.Parameters.Add("@folio", SqlDbType.VarChar).value=folionew;` (esto asumiendo que folio es varchar).
Una vez hecho esto, cambiamos de lugar donde está definido el parámetro, de forma que sólo quedaría así: `comand.Parameters.Add("@folio", SqlDbType.VarChar);`

Con eso, dentro del ciclo sólo asignas el nuevo valor al parámetro, ahorrando el crear y eliminar el comando en cada iteración: `comand.Parameters["@folio"].Value=folionew;`

El código completo quedaría algo como esto:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadenacc);
SqlDataAdapter adaptran = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();
conn.Open();
SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
comand.Transaction = tran;
string query = "INSERT INTO ... (FOLIO...) VALUES (@folio,...)";
comand.CommandText = query;
comand.Connection = conn;
comand.Parameters.Add("@folio", SqlDbType.VarChar);
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grid.Rows)
    {
        comand.Parameters["@folio"].Value=folionew;
        comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
tran.Commit();
```

Comment: OK, en esta ocasion no se debe usar Parameters.AddWithValue? que sugieres

Comment: No he tenido la necesidad de hacer algo como lo que intentas, pero [encontré esto en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand), ojalá te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Gracias solo tenia que borrar los parametros al fina.

Answer (score 0):

solo agregue esta linea comand.Parameters.Clear(); despues del ExecuteNonQuery. Esto me guarda asi tenga una sola fila mi grid o las que tenga.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadenacc);
    SqlDataAdapter adaptran = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
    comand.Transaction = tran;
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grid.Rows)
        {
string query = "INSERT INTO ... (FOLIO...) VALUES (@folio,...)";
            comand.CommandText = query;
            comand.Connection = conn;
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", folionew);
            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comand.Parameters.Clear();
}
    tran.Commit();
```